# Is there a way to export value stream map in gocd?

Tags: continuous-integration, export, pipeline, go-cd, vsm

In GoCD pipeline, we can export a pipeline metadata as json or xml. Same way, is it possible to export all the pipelines that belongs to a value stream map?

Answer (score 0):

There's an undocumented API that I use in [gocd-janitor](https://github.com/ashwanthkumar/gocd-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/in/ashwanthkumar/gocd/client/GoCD.java#L79).

The API works like this

```
"/go/pipelines/value_stream_map/" + pipeline + "/" + version + ".json"
```

- `pipeline` is the name of the pipeline
- `version` is the pipeline counter for which you need the VSM.

PS: Removing the `.json` at the end should open the VSM for that pipeline and run in a HTML format.